# Is it possible to have sound notifications when using Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a server where I have a mix of [Jenkins Pipelines](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) (my team) and FreeStyle projects (other team). I use [Build Monitor Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Monitor+Plugin) to see my Pipelines in a TV.

**I want to have sound notifications per Pipeline.**

What I have tried so far:

1. [HTML Audio Notifier plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Html+Audio+Notifier): Doesn't allow me to specify which build has notification and which don't so all of them sound, including other team's.
2. [Jenkins Sound Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Sounds+plugin): It allows to configure in freestyle projects but doesn't allow me in Pipelines :-(

So... **is there any other way**?

Answer (score 1):

You can make Jenkins Sounds play by visiting the playSound url in your pipeline, thus:

```
httpRequest 'https://jenkins.example.com/sounds/playSound?src=https://jenkins.example.com/userContent/sounds/success.wav'
```

Comment: This does not work as of today, can you embed it into a working declarative pipeline script and update the answer.